# Keep haml code in a variable and use it then

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I want to do somethings like this and I don't know if it's possible.  Also I know this isn't a good practice but I am in a deadline.

In my **_buttons.html.haml**

```haml
- buttons = case params[:action]
- when 'edit'
  %a.property-save{ href: "#" }
    %i.icon-save.icon-2x
    = t('.property_save')
  ...
- when 'show'
  ...
- else
  %a.property-save{ href: "#" }
    %i.icon-open.icon-2x
    = t('.property_open')

.my-butons
  = buttons
```

The problem is the html code is rendered and I don't know how I put on these code inside the **buttons** variable.
Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The direct way to do what you want is to use the [`capture_haml` helper](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#capture_haml-instance_method) to capture a block into a string to reuse later:

```
- buttons = case params[:action]
- when 'edit'
  - capture_haml do
    %a.property-save{ href: "#" }
      %i.icon-save.icon-2x
      = t('.property_save')
    ...
- when 'show'
  - capture_haml do
    ...
- else
  - capture_haml do
    %a.property-save{ href: "#" }
      %i.icon-open.icon-2x
      = t('.property_open')

.my-butons
  = buttons
```

You do seem to have a lot of repetition in the block, a better way might be something like:

```
.my-buttons
  %a.property-save{ href: "#" }
    %i.icon-2x{:class => "icon-#{params[:action]}"}
    = t(".property_#{params[:action]}")
```

You’d have to adapt this to your real data, but note the value of the `class` attribute will be formed by merging the `icon-2x` and the result of the hash, so you can avoid some duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Assign value to `buttons` inside your when statements. And avoid doing these logic in Views.

```
- case params[:action]
- when 'edit'
  %a.property-save{ href: "#" }
    %i.icon-save.icon-2x
    - buttons = t('.property_save')
- else
  %a.property-save{ href: "#" }
    %i.icon-open.icon-2x
    - buttons = t('.property_open')

.my-butons
  = buttons
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is when I've got more than one %a... inside of when clause. And I agree with you, this code is perfect for use in a helper method.

Comment: "I've got more than one %a." I see only one %a in each clause

Comment: sorry was my fault, I'll update the question. In my code I've got 3 when clauses and each has got 3 %a elements.

Comment: I still see only one %a for each when cluase